# mongodb is not starting in mac M1

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

My mongodb was not working On my mac M1 so uninstalled and reinstalled from below link.

```
https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v6.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/
```

still it is giving me below error.
I tried many ways still it is not working.

```
    (.venv) ➜  ~ mongosh                                             
    Current Mongosh Log ID: 64c36fac92a4a12f2de20a84
    Connecting to:      mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.10.1
    MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    (.venv) ➜  ~
```

Please let me know how can i solve this.

brew services restart mongodb/brew/mongodb-community
I tried this too

le":"src/mongo/db/storage/wiredtiger/wiredtiger_kv_engine.cpp","line":708}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-07-28T13:03:16.746+05:30"},"s":"F",  "c":"ASSERT",   "id":23092,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"\n\n***aborting after fassert() failure\n\n"}

This is the error in log.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the `mongodb-community@6.0` service first

To check if your `mongodb-community@6.0` is running

- `brew services list`
- If you dont find `mongodb-community`

Command to start `mongodb-community` service

- `brew services start mongodb-community@6.0`

Comment: Bootstrap failed: 5: Input/output error
Try re-running the command as root for richer errors.
Error: Failure while executing; `/bin/launchctl bootstrap gui/501 /Users/soubhagyakumar/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb-community.plist` exited with 5.

Comment: Try running it with `sudo`, if that doesnt work, `brew update
brew upgrade`  `brew uninstall mongodb-community
brew install mongodb-community`

Comment: still same. i reinstalled.

Comment: Don't run with `sudo`; (almost) never a need to do so and it's a security thing.  Try running `mongod` directly in another shell in the foreground, e.g.:
`mongod --dbpath ~/path/to/yourDB --logpath /tmp/mongo.log --bind_ip_all`
Verify that it actually starts, then in another window try to connect with `mongosh`:
`mongosh mongodb://localhost:27017`
Your paths and ports can vary of course.